# how to make Django recognize javascript variables and don't raise: VariableDoesNotExist?

Tags: javascript, django, django-filter

I created a custom filter for the Django template and now I need to make filtering by queryset in Django like so:

```
@register.filter
def get_data(value, arg):
    return [value.get(id=arg).error_type, value.get(id=arg).student.student]
```

now by this query, I need to show it when the user hovering one of images but of course, this filter use id to get the specific data filter so, I get this id from dataset attribute from HTML so, the code will look like that now in script:

```
<script>
        elem_hovers.hover(function () {
            let data_pk = $(this).data('pk');
            console.log(data_pk); // will return correct id number
            console.log("{{ resp|get_data:data_pk|safe }}") // variable does not exist
        })
</script>
```

in the last line above will raise the next error: variable does not exist
however, if I used the real number which is not coming from a variable which is: 12219 and that is the id number and I used it like so:

**`console.log("{{ resp|get_data:12219|safe }}")`** then I will get an expected result from filter.

so the general question now how can I make Django recognize the javascript variable dynamically without any error occurs?